Flutter Web footer not aligned below the body content
The widget.body content could be any scrollable content as the user navigates to across the app, the Problem is the footer is aligning at the bottom of the screen and not below the widge.body content, this is my AppLayout file which is used in app.dart file,
    class AppLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  /// {@macro app_layout}
  const AppLayout({required this.body, super.key});

  final Widget body;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final isDesktopFrame = DeviceInfo.of(context).deviceType.isDesktop;
    final isAuthenticated =
        context.watch<AuthenticationCubit>().state.dataOrNull != null;
    final showWebLayout = isDesktopFrame && isAuthenticated;

    return Material(
      child: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) => CustomScrollView(
          scrollBehavior: const MaterialScrollBehavior(),
          slivers: [
            if (showWebLayout) const WebHeader(),
            SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: ConstrainedBox(
                constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: constraints.maxHeight),
                child: body,
              ),
            ),
            if (showWebLayout)
              const SliverFillRemaining(
                hasScrollBody: false,
                child: WebFooter(),
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

I want to show the footer on every page below the widget.body content, currently it's displayed at the bottom of screen instead below the body content.
